# How to implement form builder plugin in grails

Tags: grails, groovy

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1.create grails project on STS: 2.9.2
2.Open plugin manager, install form builder plugin.

1.Create grails project on NetBeans IDE 7.0
2.Open Grails Plugins. install form builder plugin.

1.Create grails application using command grails create-app test
2.install form builder plugin.

**What is the expected output? What do you see instead?**

Each time i was expecting plugin should install and i can run application, but getting several dependencies. I tried with/without changes made in BuildConfig.groovy.

**What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?**

I am working on
Java: 1.6.0_29; Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM 20.4-b02
System: Windows XP version 5.1 running on x86; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
with grails 2.0.4
I have installed STS 2.9.2, STS 2.5.1, Netbeans 7.0 with grails plugin

Please provide any additional information below.

Each time i tried to install plugin it is showing me some run-time dependencies for jquery, jquery ui and others, I tried to install all plugins before installing form builder plugin. Now it is showing me some class missing 
net.sf.json-lib:json-lib:2.4.

some time it is showing me error about 
C:\Documents and Settings\jitendrakarma.grails\2.0.4\projects\FormTest\plugins\form-builder-0.1\grails-app\controllers\org\grails\formbuilder\FormController.groovy: 18: unable to resolve class freemarker.template.Template
 @ line 18, column 1.
   import freemarker.template.Template

Please let me know what is wrong with the process i am following.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything totally right. The plugin itself does not manage its dependencies correctly. Also it is belonging to some classes that doesn't exists any more in Grails >= 2.x.x

If you add all missing external dependencies and add the following entries to the plugin closure of *grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy*

```
compile ":form-builder:0.1"
compile ":jquery-ui:1.8.6"
compile ":dynamic-domain-class:0.2.1"
compile ":jquery-json:2.2"
compile ":freemarker-tags:0.5.8"
compile ":uni-form:1.5"
compile ":jquery-datatables:1.7.5"
compile ":jquery-validation-ui:1.2"
compile ":lang-selector:0.3"
compile ":quartz:0.4.2"
compile ":jquery-form-builder:0.1"
```

and add the following entry to the dependencies section of the same file

```
compile 'org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.19'
```

you will still get four compile errors.

One of them is: "unable to resolve class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.metaclass.TagLibDynamicMethods"

If you look up this class in the grails api documentation you will see it inside the grails [1.3.7 version](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.7/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/metaclass/TagLibDynamicMethods.html) but it is missing in the [2.0.4 version](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.4/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/metaclass/).

So the best thing I could recommend you is to search for another plugin or doing some code by your own.

Validation for example could be done with a [Command](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#commandObjects) on the grails side and the [JQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) on the client side. The form itself can be created with the help of scaffolding. Even if you don't need a domain you could create one run scaffolding to get the resulting form and throw away the domain.